# First UITableView cell/row will not show reorder icon

Tags: ios

Bottom line up front: I want all my rows/cells in my table to show the reorder icon upon first view.

Background: Upon initial view of a table, row 0 (first cell) in the table will not show the reorder icon, however subsequent cells will show it. I am using UITableViewCell to build my table. NSLog shows (see below) that editing (which allows reorder icon to appear) is initially not enabled for row 0, however it is for later rows. After I scroll row 0 out of view, upon its return to view editing is enabled thus allowing me to see the reorder icon (again see NSLog below). I think this might be a reuse issue, however I have UILabels in all the rows, to include row 0, that show up fine. I think this is a simple fix, but just can't figure it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

2011-03-13 12:48:57.750 VBStat[4305:207] row: 0 editing: 0 indexPath: 81108000

2011-03-13 12:48:57.751 VBStat[4305:207] row: 1 editing: 1 indexPath: 81108144

2011-03-13 12:48:57.752 VBStat[4305:207] row: 2 editing: 1 indexPath: 81108224

2011-03-13 12:48:57.753 VBStat[4305:207] row: 3 editing: 1 indexPath: 81108304

2011-03-13 12:48:57.753 VBStat[4305:207] row: 4 editing: 1 indexPath: 81108384

2011-03-13 12:48:57.754 VBStat[4305:207] row: 5 editing: 1 indexPath: 81108464

2011-03-13 12:49:32.469 VBStat[4305:207] row: 0 editing: 1 indexPath: 81108000

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *CellTableIdentifier = @"CellTableIdentifier ";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:    CellTableIdentifier];

NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
NSDictionary *rowData = [self.list objectAtIndex:row];





   //stuff for labels...
        UILabel *name = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:kNameValueTag];
        name.text = [rowData objectForKey:@"Name"];
        UILabel *color = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:kColorValueTag];
        color.text = [rowData objectForKey:@"Color"];

if (cell == nil) {
{   cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellTableIdentifier] autorelease];

    NSLog(@"row: %i editing: %d indexPath: %d rowData %d", row, tableView.editing, indexPath, rowData);

    ...Labels generated here... 
}

tableView.editing = YES; 
cell.showsReorderControl=YES;

 }
```

Comment: Fixed row 0 editing 0 problem by moving tableView.editing out of the if statement. Now shows row 0 editing 1 in NSLog, but it still does not show the reorder icon...uggg...

Comment: More info...did another NSLog and watched the action in Debugger Console. Noticed that showsReorderContol upon initial view is set to 0 for all cells which I assume means it is not set even though the reorder control appears for all the cells except the first (row 0). After scrolling occurs reorder is then set to 1 for all rows at which time the reorder control in row 0 appears. I am now assuming I have to insert cell.showReorderingControl somewhere else so that it is set when the table first appears, but where do I insert it?

Answer (score 0):

did you implement methods

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableview canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  return YES; 
  }
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath {

}

and... you need to move this up after

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:    CellTableIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
{   cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellTableIdentifier] autorelease];

    NSLog(@"row: %i editing: %d indexPath: %d rowData %d", row, tableView.editing, indexPath, rowData);

    ...Labels generated here... 
}
```

because you use (UILabel *)[cell.contentView in your first row when cell is even not exist

Comment: Yes, I did implement both methods. Regarding, (UILabel *)...I commented out everything that had to do with UILabels to see if it changed anything and it did not. BTW, not too proud of what I did (because I want to find out is causing my issue) but I did do a work around. Since the view I need happens after a scroll, I implemented an autoscroll upon first view (used scrollRectToVisible and scrollToRowAtIndexPath). I suspect that Apple wants you to implement the reorder control from an action like a tool bar button, rather than loading automatically on first view like I am trying to do. Thanks!